# ClojureDart - How to translate .of(context) into ClojureDart?

Tags: dart, clojure

```dart
class SnackBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SnackBarPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );

          // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
          // and use it to show a SnackBar.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        },
        child: const Text('Show SnackBar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Above is the code that I want to translate into ClojureDart.
However, ClojureDart is a dialect of Clojure which is a functional language,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!
I had to use `cljd.flutter.alpha` library that exports `f/widget`, and wraps it around the scaffold.
Then, within the widget, I had to use the `inherit` keyword with the widget I wanted to inherit, in my case, `ScaffoldMessenger`. After doing so, I have access to the `ScaffoldMessenger` object with a variable with a kebab-case name. While it can be confusing without seeing it, it gives something like that :

```clj
(f/widget
:inherit [m/ScaffoldMessenger]
(m/Scaffold
...
:onPressed (.showSnackBar scaffold-messenger snackbar)
...))
```

With `scaffold-messenger` variable corresponding to `m/ScaffoldMessenger`, and `snackbar` being a function that returns a `m/SnackBar` widget.